# Power Bi Cohort Analysis Custom Subtotal

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI everything is working as expected but I have a need for a custom subtotal on my retention rate cohort matrix. For instance for the Month 3 I can not simply take 1098 / 2606 which is what is happening today. I need to take the 1098 / 2606 - 80 (from the September 2022 Cohort)

Month 4 would then be 969 / 2606 - 55 - 68 so on so forth ....

[Cohort Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5inZ.png)

Not sure how to create custom subtotals given the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current context with some information functions like:

ISFILTERED, HASONEVALUE and others.

With SELECTEDVALUE() you can identify if you are in the context of a specific member.

```
measure = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Start of Month]) = "April 2021", [one measure], [other measure])
```